# Replace or modify API call (GetOpenFileName, GetSaveFileName) in foreign application

Tags: c++, winapi, crash, hook, .net-assembly

I have an old application which calls GetOpenFileNameA and GetSaveFileNameA.
Both calls are erroneous. The application crashes!
I have used OllyDbg and API Monitor to read the size stored in the OPENFILENAME struct.
The size of the struct is 76 Bytes (testing with Windows 7 x64). 
I get an access violation exception while GetOpenFileNameA or GetSaveFileNameA is called.
I assume that at runtime windows tries to read 88 Bytes instead of 76 Bytes.
Have a look at this:
http://dotnetbutchering.blogspot.de/2007/10/vc-60-getting-0xc0000005-access.html
and this
http://www.asmcommunity.net/board/index.php?topic=5768.15

I did some research and while doing that I have detected following behavior:
While running Microsoft Spy++ the application does not crash!!
I stepped through the debugger and I saw that the access violation exception still occurs but somehow the exception is swallowed.
The application works fine! I can load and save files.

I have the following ideas. What do you think about them?

1. write sth. like a Loader.exe which does the same like Spy++. 
   Swallowing the access violation exception when both APIs are called.
2. Use DLL Injection and API Hooking.
   I could hook GetOpenFileName and GetSaveFileName with a custom implementation in a custom DLL. My implementation would fix the struct and pass the corrected struct to the original API calls.
3. Use SetWindowsHook to hook a window message ?!?!?!
4. Patch the binary file. Is it possible to fix this struct size issue by patching using a HEX Editor?

Which one would work?
Do you have a better idea how I can fix this?

I am not able to get the source code of this old application.
I have to fix it using the existing binaries.
My solution must work at least on Windows XP and Windows 7 (x86, x64)

The tool PEiD shows me following info about the old application:
Linker info: 2.55
MS Visual C++ 4.0

Comment: You are wrong, there is nothing erroneous about a specific size of the `struct`. This is exactly why there is a `lStructSize` member in the  `struct`. You will notice that there is a `#if (_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0500)` in the type definition of the headers. It's possible MS dropped the ball concerning backward compatibility. You could try using PCA/Shims to make it work instead of hackery.

Comment: I have already tried it using Shims. It didn't help. I always get an access violation exception when one of the APIs are called.

Comment: This is no doubt strongly connected with an appcompat issue on the 64-bit version of Windows.  The story is quite ugly, detailed very well in this blog post: http://blog.paulbetts.org/index.php/2010/07/20/the-case-of-the-disappearing-onload-exception-user-mode-callback-exceptions-in-x64/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The size of the struct is 76 Bytes (testing with Windows 7 x64). I get
>   an access violation exception while GetOpenFileNameA or
>   GetSaveFileNameA is called. I assume that at runtime windows tries to
>   read 88 Bytes instead of 76 Bytes.

if you look at the `OPENFILENAME` `struct` you will notice a:

```
#if (_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0500)
  void *        pvReserved;
  DWORD         dwReserved;
  DWORD         FlagsEx;
#endif // (_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0500)
```

which in a 32bit program (VC++ 4 did not support 64bit targets) translates to exactly 12 bytes difference. As long as `lStructSize` is set properly by the caller, this should not be an issue at all. It may be worthwhile to use `procdump` from Microsoft/Sysinternals to get a minidump of the exact state (or attach a debugger and investigate). The exception you encounter does not necessarily have to be due to the `struct` size. If it is, it is more likely that Microsoft dropped the ball when it comes to backward compatibility of this function. Obviously `OPENFILENAME::lStructSize` is there for versioning of the `struct` and to ensure what you encounter wouldn't happen. But then, we're talking about a program built with a compiler/linker from times before Windows 2000.

> write sth. like a Loader.exe which does the same like Spy++.
>   Swallowing the access violation exception when both APIs are called.
>   It's a fair point. If you would insert exception handling at the top level you could do things you want, but it may cause side-effects depending on what exactly caused the exception (i.e. which exact memory was overwritten).
>
> Use DLL Injection and API Hooking. I could hook GetOpenFileName and
>   GetSaveFileName with a custom implementation in a custom DLL. My
>   implementation would fix the struct and pass the corrected struct to
>   the original API calls.
>   This is pretty much related to the first one. I think it will be easiest and safest in all, because this way you can correct the behavior without too much intrusion. Please read further below. Also, check out NInjectLib.
>
> Use SetWindowsHook to hook a window message ?!?!?!
>   I don't see how that helps other than facilitating the injection of a DLL (for 1. and 2.).
>
> Patch the binary file. Is it possible to fix this struct size issue by
>   patching using a HEX Editor?
>   This may be the trickiest, depending on whether the `OPENFILENAME` is inside the binary (initialized data) or on stack or whether it gets allocated on the heap (easy then).

---

One possible hybrid approach for 1. and 2. would be this:

1. Add a subkey to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options` named after the program that you are executing (e.g. `foo.exe`)
2. Create a `REG_SZ` value named `Debugger` inside that newly-created subkey and set the value to a program that I will try to describe briefly now.

This effectively sets up a debugger for this old application of yours and it means that the debugger we're going to write will receive your application's command line as arguments. It is convenient, because it is transparent to the end-user and you can adjust it to suit your needs.

You'll need to write a debugger. This task isn't as taunting as it seems at first, because you can use the debugging helpers Win32 offers. The gist is in the debugger loop. In general you create the target process yourself using `CreateProcess` passing the appropriate flags to be able to debug it. The use `WaitForDebugEvent` and `ContinueDebugEvent` to control the execution. For all practical purposes you may not even need the debugger loop at all, because you could create the main thread of the target application suspended (pass `CREATE_SUSPENDED` to `CreateProcess`) and then point the `CONTEXT` of the main thread to your own code at the very beginning, then call `ResumeThread(pi.hThread)`. This way you will be done before the main thread starts. However, this may cause issues due to the way `kernel32.dll`'s `CreateThread` works (which involves registering the new thread with the Win32 subsystem aka `csrss.exe`). So it may be advisable to instead patch the IAT of the target in memory or something similar. After all you are merely interested in two functions.

Check out the two articles [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43682/Writing-a-basic-Windows-debugger) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/132742/Writing-Windows-Debugger-Part-2) for a more detailed look at the topic.

I for one prefer writing my debuggers based on `PyDbg` from [PaiMei](https://github.com/OpenRCE/paimei), but I have admittedly not tried to use such a Python-based debugger in `Image File Execution Options`.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I am going to check your suggestions.

Comment: I have done it with NInjectLib. Works very well... Hooked the API call used the passed OFN to fill a new 88 Bytes long OFN struct. Called the original function with new OFN struct. Awesome!

Answer (score 1):

(1) Would be pure hack which can be hard to do (what aspect of Spy++ behavior does it? Or you want to reinvent complete Syp++?), and even if you do that, how can you be sure the application will work correctly (for all input) after the 'swallowed exception'? Internal state of the program can be undefined and lead to other problems later.

(2) Assuming you don't have sources so you cannot fix it in a normal way, this IMHO seems the to be best work around of the issue.

(3) I can't see how this could help you.

(4) Possible but a lot of work probably. Assuming there are some data on the stack, then by resizing one of them (the `OPENFILENAMEA` struct) you move offsets of others so you will have to 'fix' references to those.